# Reactjs add/delete input fields with scrollable container

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am a new reactJS developer and am looking to create a container that holds an input field where you can add/delete new fields. I want all of this to be in a scrollable container but instead, my code adds new inputs but moves the rest of the page and doesn't stay in the container. Below is the react and css. The css also has some fields I am going to include later

React

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './Dropdown.css'

function Dropdown() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ courseName: "", courseRating: "" }]);
  
  // handle input change
  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handleRemoveClick = index => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Add button
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([...inputList, { courseName: "", courseRating: "" }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="base-container-drop">
      <div className="content-drop">
      {inputList.map((x, i) => {
        return (
          <div className="container-for-drop">
              <div className="form-drop">
                <div className="form-group-drop">
                  <label className="label-drop" htmlFor="courseName"></label>
                  <input className="input-drop"
                    name="courseName"
                    placeholder="Course Name"
                    value={x.firstName}
                    onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group-drop-rating">
                    <label className="label-drop" htmlFor="courseRating"></label>
                    <input className="input-drop"
                    type="number"
                    name="courseRating"
                    placeholder="0"
                    max='10'
                    min='0'
                    value={x.lastName}
                    onChange={e => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="btn-box">
                  {inputList.length !== 1 && <button
                    onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}
                    className="Remove">
                      Remove
                    </button>}
                    <div className="sep"/>
                  {inputList.length - 1 === i && <button onClick={handleAddClick}
                  className="Add">
                    Add
                    </button>}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        );
      })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Dropdown;
```

CSS

```
.base-comntainer-drop {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.content-drop {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.base-container-drop{
  width:100%; 
  overflow-y:auto; 
  position:relative;
  max-height: 30%;
}

.form-drop{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: .5em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: .7%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  

}

.form-group-drop{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.form-group-drop-rating{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -25%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-group-drop .input-drop {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}


.label-drop {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.form-group-drop .input-drop{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f3f3f5;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  margin: 0;
}
.form-group-drop-rating .input-drop{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f3f3f5;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  margin: 0;
}
.input-drop :focus{
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px .8px #0e81ce96;
}

.btn-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: auto;
}
.Add{
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.Remove {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}

.Add:hover{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #6568F4;
}
.Remove:hover{
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #6568F4;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .base-comntainer-drop {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .content-drop {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  
  .form-drop{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: .5em;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: .7%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    
  
  }
  
  .form-group-drop{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 1%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .form-group-drop-rating{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 50%;
    margin: -25%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 13%;
    
  }
  
  .form-group-drop .input-drop {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  
  .label-drop {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .form-group-drop .input-drop{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 200%;
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f5;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 75%;
  }
  .form-group-drop-rating .input-drop{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 30%;
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f5;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 75% ;
  }
  .input-drop :focus{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px .8px #0e81ce96;
  }
  
  .btn-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 15%;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .btn-box .sep {
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  .Add{
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #3498db;
    border: 0;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .Remove {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: #3498db;
    border: 0;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .Add:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6568F4;
  }
  .Remove:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6568F4;
  }
  
}
```

Comment: The ask is a bit confusing for me to understand. Let's see we can break it down. So the workflow as you have it setup. 1) Add a new item 2) that new item goes to the bottom of the list. So, is that workflow the expectation? Or you just want that entire, let's say `Dropdown` components to go inside a scrollable container? I created a sandbox with your example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-h1iqr

Comment: Yes, I apologize it isn't clear! I would like each new dropdown to go below and then the entire Dropdown component go inside a scrollable container so it only takes up, say, 20% of the page or so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I extended off you a bit and created a `ScrollableContainer`. The idea is to make it modular and reusable so you can put anything into it, your `Dropdown` or anything else. By default the height is `20%` but you can set `height='yourNumber'` to set your own limit.

I also removed the 30% off your container on the dropdown for this to be effective.

Here is the updated:

JS

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function Dropdown() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([
    { courseName: "", courseRating: "" }
  ]);

  // handle input change
  const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    const list = [...inputList];
    list[index][name] = value;
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Remove button
  const handleRemoveClick = (index) => {
    const list = [...inputList];
    list.splice(index, 1);
    setInputList(list);
  };

  // handle click event of the Add busutton
  const handleAddClick = () => {
    setInputList([...inputList, { courseName: "", courseRating: "" }]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="base-container-drop">
      <div className="content-drop">
        {inputList.map((x, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="container-for-drop">
              <div className="form-drop">
                <div className="form-group-drop">
                  <label className="label-drop" htmlFor="courseName"></label>
                  <input
                    className="input-drop"
                    name="courseName"
                    placeholder="Course Name"
                    value={x.firstName}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group-drop-rating">
                  <label className="label-drop" htmlFor="courseRating"></label>
                  <input
                    className="input-drop"
                    type="number"
                    name="courseRating"
                    placeholder="0"
                    max="10"
                    min="0"
                    value={x.lastName}
                    onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="btn-box">
                  {inputList.length !== 1 && (
                    <button
                      onClick={() => handleRemoveClick(i)}
                      className="Remove"
                    >
                      Remove
                    </button>
                  )}
                  <div className="sep" />
                  {inputList.length - 1 === i && (
                    <button onClick={handleAddClick} className="Add">
                      Add
                    </button>
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function ScrollableContainer(props) {
  const height = props.height || "20%";

  return (
    <div
      className="scrollable-container"
      style={{
        height
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
}

function App(props) {
  return (
    <ScrollableContainer height="200px">
      <Dropdown />
    </ScrollableContainer>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CSS

```
.scrollable-container {
  overflow: auto;
}

.base-comntainer-drop {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.content-drop {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.base-container-drop {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* max-height: 30%; */
}

.form-drop {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 0.7%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.form-group-drop {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.form-group-drop-rating {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -25%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.form-group-drop .input-drop {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.label-drop {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.form-group-drop .input-drop {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #f3f3f5;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  margin: 0;
}
.form-group-drop-rating .input-drop {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-top: 6px;
  height: 37px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #f3f3f5;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 31px;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  margin: 0;
}
.input-drop :focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 0.8px #0e81ce96;
}

.btn-box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: auto;
}
.Add {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.Remove {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: 5%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  background-color: #3498db;
  border: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
  color: #fff;
}

.Add:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #6568f4;
}
.Remove:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #6568f4;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .base-comntainer-drop {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .content-drop {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .form-drop {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 0.7%;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .form-group-drop {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 1%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .form-group-drop-rating {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 50%;
    margin: -25%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 13%;
  }

  .form-group-drop .input-drop {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .label-drop {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .form-group-drop .input-drop {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 200%;
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f5;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 75%;
  }
  .form-group-drop-rating .input-drop {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 30%;
    margin-top: 6px;
    height: 37px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3f3f5;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 31px;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 75%;
  }
  .input-drop :focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 12px 0.8px #0e81ce96;
  }

  .btn-box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-left: 15%;
    margin: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .btn-box .sep {
    margin-top: 5%;
  }
  .Add {
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-top: 2px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    background-color: #3498db;
    border: 0;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .Remove {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    background-color: #3498db;
    border: 0;
    transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .Add:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6568f4;
  }
  .Remove:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6568f4;
  }
}
```

Updated code sandbox for preview. Just a note I set a height to 200px on ScrollableContainer, for sake of demo. But you can remove it and it will become 20% as the default: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-h1iqr